# Is mysql update query slow?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, query-optimization

I have been trying to update column from table through raw_sql in ruby on rails as below,

```
db_connection.execute("update table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.s_number = t2.product_id set t1.name = (select name from table3 where mid_size = t2.level)")
```

Its very slow and taking too much time. Is there any best approach for bulk update in rails through SQL? hope same will be happen if i do from ACTIVERECORD also.

More information table1 having the 1 lac and table2 having 2.5 lacs records

share your thoughts

Comment: Please show yout table create statements.

Comment: table1 having more than 55 fields and table2 having 2 fields only where required fields are indexed. @Jens

Answer (score 0):

It is completely dependent on your indexes in both tables.
Try `EXPLAIN` for your query it will give you insight

It would be great if you share your create table code for both of your tables